# How to overlay HTML on siilverlight without setting windowless property?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, silverlight

I had a silverlight control, which i can't set the windowless property to the control. So, is there any way to display html content on top of the silverlight control without setting the windowless property?

Any help is much appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

If you need the HTML to be displayed on top of the silverlight, you need to make an overlay DIV with css:

```
position: absolute; 
z-index: 9999; // Adjust z-index to make sure sharepoint modal dialog and dropdowns is still above it 
height: 100%; 
width: 100%;
```

Within this DIV, you place the rest of the stuff you to be displayed above the silverlight.

Example:

```
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: 9999; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <div class="MyClass">
        This is where you place the content which shall be shown on top
        of the silverlight component.
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: NO..that won't help...As i already tried that one also.Actually silver light control renders to the windows in a different layer where Z-index can be applied on the same layer.So,making it position absolute and Z-index high won't work in this case.